# Ломается страница при редактировании через визуальный редактор Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! Устанавливаю чистый Битрикс через bitrixsetup.php. При редактировании через визуальный редактор ломает страницу

index.php

```
 <div style="background-image:url(<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/banner.png);"></div>
```

в визуальном редакторе превращается в

```
 <div title="Код PHP: &lt;?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?&gt;" class="bxhtmled-surrogate">
    <?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?><span class="bxhtmled-surrogate-inner"><span class="bxhtmled-right-side-item-icon"></span><span class="bxhtmled-comp-lable" unselectable="on" spellcheck="false">Код PHP</span></span>/img/index_slider_bg.png);"&gt;
 </div>
```

Знаю можно указать сразу полный путь, но интересно из-за чего так происходит

Также при использовании включаемой области

```
<?
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include",
    "",
    array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
        "PATH" => SITE_DIR . "include/promo.php",
        "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N"
    ),
);
?>
```

например в include/promo.php такой текст

```
<div><p>Текст</p></div>
```

при редактировании через визуальный редактор, почему то автоматически форматируется и в конце добавляется `<br>`

```
<div>
    <p>
        Текст
    </p>
</div>
<br>
```

Использую версию php8 кодировка utf8. При проверки системы никаких ошибок нет. Обновлен до последней версии

Кто знает как отключить это форматирование?

Answer (score 0):

Нашла только чтобы в включаемой области в конце не добавлялся `<br>`

Открываем файл `/bitrix/js/fileman/html_editor/html-views.js`

Находим эти две строчки и нужно их закомментировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]